# Some difficulties of designing with types in F# by simple graph example

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

There is oriented graph:

[image]

We are adding node and edge to it:

[image]

and then removing some other (by the algorithm, it doesn't matter here):

[image]

I had tried to do this in F#, but I cannot choose properly architecture decisions because of my little experience.

```
open System.Collections.Generic

type Node = Node of int
type OGraph(nodes : Set<Node>,
            edges : Dictionary<Node * int, Node>) =
    member this.Nodes = nodes
    member this.Edges = edges

let nodes = set [Node 1; Node 2; Node 3]
let edges = Dictionary<Node * int, Node>()
Array.iter edges.Add [|
    (Node 1, 10), Node 2;
    (Node 2, 20), Node 3;
|]
let myGraph = OGraph(nodes, edges)

myGraph.Nodes.Add (Node 4)
myGraph.Edges.Add ((Node 2, 50), Node 4)

myGraph.Edges.Remove (Node 2, 20)
myGraph.Nodes.Remove (Node 3)
```

1. How to add empty node? I mean, it may be 3 or 4 or even 100500. If we add node without number, then how we can use it to create edge? `myGraph.Edges.Add ((Node 2, 50), ???)` In imperative paradigm it would be simple because of using named references and Nulls, we can just create `Node newNode = new Node()` and then use this reference `newNode`, but seems that in F# this is a bad practice.
2. Should I specify separate types Node and Edge or use simple types instead? Or may be some other representation, more complicated?
3. It is better to use common .NET mutable collections (HashSet, Dictionary etc.), or special F# collections (Set, Map, etc.)? If collections are large, it is acceptable in terms of performance to copy entire collection every time it should be changed?

Comment: Why would you ever add an unlabeled node? Does it make sense in your context at all, apart from adding a node unlabeled and immediately setting the label on it?

Comment: No, on the contrary it would be better for me to indicate nodes by unique references and enumerate them only before graph displaying. It is what I woluld doing in imperative language

Answer (score 3):

The graph itself is easy enough to model. You could define it like this:

```
type Graph = { Node : int option; Children : (int * Graph) list }
```

If you will, you can embellish it more, using either type aliases or custom types instead of primitive `int` values, but this is the basic idea.

You can model the three graphs pictured in the OP like the following. The formatting I've used looks quite verbose, but I deliberately formatted the values this way in order to make the structure clearer; you could write the values in a more compact form, if you'd like.

```
let x1 =
    {
        Node = Some 1;
        Children =
            [
                (
                    10,
                    {
                        Node = Some 2;
                        Children =
                            [
                                (
                                    20,
                                    {
                                        Node = Some 3;
                                        Children = []
                                    }
                                )
                            ]
                    }
                )
            ]
        }
let x2 =
    {
        Node = Some 1;
        Children =
            [
                (
                    10,
                    {
                        Node = Some 2;
                        Children =
                            [
                                (
                                    20,
                                    {
                                        Node = Some 3;
                                        Children = []
                                    }
                                );
                                (
                                    50,
                                    {
                                        Node = None;
                                        Children = []
                                    }
                                )
                            ]
                    }
                )
            ]
        }
let x3 =
    {
        Node = Some 1;
        Children =
            [
                (
                    10,
                    {
                        Node = Some 2;
                        Children =
                            [
                                (
                                    50,
                                    {
                                        Node = Some 3;
                                        Children = []
                                    }
                                )
                            ]
                    }
                )
            ]
        }
```

Notice the use of `int option` to capture whether or not a node has a value.

The `Graph` type is an F# record type, and uses the F# workhorse `list` for the children. This would be my default choice, and only if performance becomes a problem would I consider other data types. Lists are easy to work with.

Comment: Note that this can only represent acyclic graphs, and that there's nothing preventing multiple nodes with the same ID.

Comment: Right. It wasn't apparent to me if those were requirements, but they are, a different design would be required. It'd probably make the manipulation of the graph more difficult as well...

Answer (score 0):

Sine if these are easy:

1. Use Option - then an empty node is None
2. Maybe - depends on problem
3. This depends on your specific problem you are solving - the F# collections tend to be immutable and some operations are fast, but the .NET collections have other operations which are fast.

Comment: 1. If we are adding two nodes and they both are None, then how we can differ them? 2. What operation may be fast if entire collection are copied from start to end?

Comment: Well if they are both None then they are the same as they are empty by definition. 2. Consider for example an F# list `a` then `1::a` is very fast

Comment: 1. For example, node1 and node2 are both empty so they are seems the same, but there are edges (node1, 4, node3) and (node2, 8, node3), that makes node1 and node2 different. 2. I think we should consider memory cost also. However, I mean my concrete cases.

Comment: @Feofilakt Entire collections don't get copied. In an immutable environment you can reference previous datastructures safely because they don't change. Adding an element to an list is basically (1) create a new element (2) Let it point to the old list. You only need full copying of data-structures in an mutable world. In an immutable list: Adding/Removing from the beginning is fast. In an mutable array adding/removing at the end is fast. And the opposites are slow.

Comment: @Sid Burn Thanks, I read that in case of immutability new objects are created instead of changing every time and I wrongly thought that performance was sacrificed for functional approach.